# How to put initramfs and kernel on two separate partition?

Tags: linux, boot, initramfs

I'd like to put the initramfs on a USB device will keeping the linux kernel on the SSD, so I get the fast boot while protecting my encryption settings on the USB device. Any idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

in grub,
Normally, in the booting proccess it decides what initrd to use, if any.

In a plain boot, when doing the "grub-update" (or manually) you find where it is, and add that part into the *grub.cfg* file (/boot/grub/grub.cfg or /boot/grub.cfg or lots of other locations.)

Assuming it will be on partition 2 (and partitiond using gpt) for example, will have the line.

```
initrd (hd0,gpt2)/boot/initrd
```

Or more normally,

```
set root=(hd0,gpt2)
initrd /boot/initrd
```

Assuming the USB will always be the second hard-disk-type of thing, you can change the first line, or the last part of second one into

```
initrd (hd1,gpt1)/initrd
```

(initrd==initramfs.) If using different type of partition might need to load the grub module that can deel with it, "insmod blah"

To see if you can get this done, might help having both a normal install, and a copy of the initrd in the USB, then in grub choose command line, and try to do the whole thing yourself. (

```
set root=(hd0,gpt..)
set prefix=(hd0,gpt..)/grub    (or wherever the grub things are)
linux /boot/vmlinuz
initrd (hd1,gpt1)/initrd
```

)

might need to change things, according to distribution. Also, might need some _insmod_s in there.

(If everything works, there might be a way to make grub do it itself that way, using grub-update. have a look at /etc/default/grub or wherever that is)